# Fail to load a wasm file in a Web application

Tags: javascript, apache, fetch, mime-types, webassembly

I'm trying to host a website, and I use a .wasm file with .js scripts created by the wasm-pack tool.

I tested the project locally with *npm* and *node.js* and everything worked fine.

But Then I hosted it on a raspberry (apache2), and when I try to access it, I get in the following error:

> `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/wasm". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

#### details

There are multiple files, but here is the idea:

my index.html loads the module `bootstrap.js`

```
// bootstrap.js content
import("./index.js").catch(e => console.error("Error importing `index.js`:", e));
```

my main code is in the `index.js`, which calls `test_wasm_bg.js`

And finally, `test_wasm_bg.js` loads the wasm file with this line:

```
// test_wasm_bg.js first line
import * as wasm from './test_wasm_bg.wasm';
```

---

Where is the problem?

What is the right way to load a web assembly file?

Comment: You can't import a wasm,. Use fetch instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running

Comment: Ok, thank's for the link ! But to use "InstanciateStreaming", you need an ImportObjetc. What is that ?

Comment: ImportObjects is just an object you create with functions etc you want to expose to the wasm module.  If you don't expose any you could just send `{}`.  This link might help you more -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API  The example shown is also on github -> https://github.com/mdn/webassembly-examples/blob/master/js-api-examples/instantiate-streaming.html

Comment: when I try to do that I get the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0  module="./test_wasm_bg.js" error: module is not an object or function`

Comment: `test_wasm_bg.js`, did you mean to do `test_wasm_bg.wasm`

Comment: No It was a typo: I tried with both and loading test_wasm_bg.wasm also failed

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see your wasm, but the error Is saying it's expecting an object called module.  So you might want importObject to be `{module:{}}`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I finally found what is the right way to load a wasm application in a `wasm-bindgen` project!

In fact, everything was on [this page](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/deployment.html)

When you compile the project without wanting to run it with a bundler, you have to run wasm-pack build with a --target flag.

`wasm-pack build --release --target web`.

This creates a .js file (`pkg/test_wasm.js` in my example) with everything you need to load the wasm-application.

And then this is how you use the functions created by wasm-bindgen (`index.js`):

```
import init, {ex_function, ex_Struct ...} from './pkg/test_wasm.js';

function run() {
    // use the function ex_function1 here

}

init().then(run)
```

You include your index.js in your HTML file

```html
<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
```

And then it work's !

## Edit:

Now that's I understand the javascript ecosystem a bit more, I cab try to explain what I understand:
There are many ways to do imports in js, here is a list :
https://dev.to/iggredible/what-the-heck-are-cjs-amd-umd-and-esm-ikm

You don't need to know much about that, except that the default target of wasm-pack is a node style [ecmascript module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html). This import will work in node.js, but not directly in the browser. So in node, you can import a function from a wasm file directly, like so:
`import {ex_function} from "./test.wasm"`

But these styles of import don't work in the browser right now. Maybe it will be possible [in the future](https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals/issues/12)
But for now, your browser only knows about js modules. So if you try to import a .wasm file directly in the browser, it will throw a mime type error because it doesn't know how to deal with webassembly files.

The tool you use to go from ecmascipt modules (with a lot of nmp packages for example) to a single js file is called a [web-bundler](https://lihautan.com/what-is-module-bundler-and-how-does-it-work/) (webpack, rollup, snowpack ...). If you work on a big project with npm, you probably need one. Otherwise, the "--target web" will say  to wasm-bindgen to instantiate the wasm module [the right way](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running) (look at the `pkg/test_wasm.js`)

Comment: 'The server responded with a non-Javascript MIME type of appliaction/WASM'. This error makes no sense to me. Can somebody explain what it means. I'm trying to use WASM and get a message saying the server responded with WASM - that error is a about as useful as Prolog's 'No'. It is 2021 - have we not advanced a tad?

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy does my edit answer your question ?

Comment: what happens if you do something like this:

```const math = awaitWebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('math.wasm'))
        .then(res => res.instance.exports)```

Comment: For me, I got the error when I forgot to add `--target=web` to `wasm-pack build`